# Use a button to navigate to a different tab

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.3

My app has four tabs.  The root view controller of the first tab (index zero) is where the log in page pops up as a modalviewcontroller, but a view controller in the fourth tab (index three) is where the log out button is.  Is there a way to programmatically set it so that when the logout button is pushed the app transitions to the tab at index zero?  I initially tried a push transition, but that made the root view controller of index zero instead show up as a view controller in index three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to programmatically change the tab, just call

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

In your case create the selector, which will be assigned to the logout button event.

```
- (IBAction) didClickLogoutButton:(id)sender {
    // do some work to log out the user...
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Hope this is what you meant.